# Else condition not working even tho there is no error

Tags: c, if-statement, relational-operators

I am making a program in c using if else conditions and it is running perfectly fine without any errors but it is not running the else condition(i.e. even if I am giving it the input where the else condition should be printed, it is giving me the else if condition and not the else condition), here is the code

```
if(Number_Of_People==1){
        printf("Show us your identification so we can proceed!");
    }
    else if(1<Number_Of_People<=6){
        printf("Show us the identification of each member so that we can proceed!");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Sorry, we dont have rooms for so many people!");
    }
```

Comment: `1<Number_Of_People<=6` does not mean what you think it means.  It is equivalent to `(1 < Number_Of_People) <= 6`, and since `1 < Number_Of_People` always evaluates to either 0 or 1, the overall condition will always evaluate to 1 (true).

Comment: BTW, try using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. It certainly catches such mistakes by giving a warning....

Comment: You want: `else if ((1 < Number_Of_People) && (Number_Of_People <= 6)) {`

Comment: I didnt actually include that part of the program, I used printf and scanf to get the value of number of people from the user itself, the code was very big so I didnt include it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression in the if statement

```
 else if(1<Number_Of_People<=6){
```

may be equivalently rewritten like

```
 else if( ( 1 < Number_Of_People ) <=6 ){
```

The relational operator `<` yields either 0 or 1 depending on whether the expression with the relational operator is logically false or true.

Thus the result of the subexpression `( 1 < Number_Of_People )` either equal to 0 or 1 in any case is less than `6`.

So this if statement will be always evaluated if the preceding if statement will be skipped.

You need to rewrite the above if operator like

```
else if( ( 1 < Number_Of_People ) && ( Number_Of_People <= 6 ) ){
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(1<Number_Of_People<=6)
```

does not do what you think it does - consider this:

```
else if(Number_Of_People > 1 && Number_Of_People<=6)
```

Note that the only thing the greater than 1 check is actually look for is 0 or negative values as you check for 1 explicitly in your first case.

Comment: Oh I get it now, you need to seperate both the conditions using the && operator